# Why can't I put value to db?

Tags: python, django

I made composite id of trunsaction_id＆user_id.I wanted to assign trunsaction_id each user_id.Now User model is

```
class User(models.Model):
    trunsaction_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    user_trunsaction_id = ''.join([str(trunsaction_id), '_', str(user_id)]
```

But when I run file of putting data to User model, all column excepting for user_trunsaction_id has its data, but no user_trunsaction_id's column is db.Of course I run makemigration&migration command,so I really cannot understand why this error happens.What is wrong?How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you show the inserting code and the error messages?

Comment: @NilsWerner What is the inserting code ?And no error messages is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Django reads your class in `models.py` to make db scheme.

But at your code `user_trunsaction_id` is NOT db field but just `User` class's attribute.

So if you want to use `user_trunsaction_id` like db field, do like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    trunsaction_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    @property
    def user_trunsaction_id(self):
        return ''.join([str(self.trunsaction_id), '_', str(self.user_id)]
```

then you can get `user_trunsaction_id` like this:

User.objects.get(pk=1).user_trunsaction_id

Comment: thx ur answer.From ur comments,I think I cannot make user_trunsaction_id column, right?(so I cannot see user_trunsaction_id from DB Browser for SQLite,right?)And what is pk=1 in ur las code?

Comment: @user8563636 last code is just example for you :) and Yes, You can NOT see that value `user_trunsaction_id` in your db. Surely you can make it with TextField.. But it is anti-pattern for your django project. Is there any reason you want to see that in your db? (Because, duplicated data is not suggested for RDB modeing)

Comment: @user8563636 If you really need it, You can do it by adding a model field and overriding the save method of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your [computed property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#model-methods) like

```
class User(models.Model):
    trunsaction_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    @property
    def user_trunsaction_id(self):
        return '%s_%s' % (self.trunsaction_id, self.user_id)
```